# How to show infinite square-free numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here's the exact wording of the problem:

"The squares, of course, are the numbers 1,4,9,... The square-free numbers are the integers 1,2,3,5,6,... which are not divisible by the square of any prime (so that 1 is both square and square-free). Show that every positive integer is uniquely representable as the product of a square and a square-free number. Show that there are infinitely many square-free numbers."

I was able to prove the first statement with a proof by contradiction, but can't figure out the second part. Does it rely on the first part?

Comment: Hint: all primes are square-free.

Answer (score 1):

As @vadim123 notes, all primes are trivially square-free, and there are an infinite number of primes, so this is sufficient for a proof. Of course multiplying together any selection of distinct primes will also give square-free numbers.

In fact, as you might expect, square-free composite numbers are denser than the primes, and also will get ahead of the "square-carrying" numbers. While the proof is several steps beyond my mathematical pay-grade, [square-free numbers are about 60% of all numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer#Distribution), which means that square-free composite numbers will eventually be more the 50% of all numbers (as the proportion of primes diminishes). This actually happens around $30400$.

The count of square-free composite numbers pulls ahead of that for square-carrying numbers much earlier, at $214$.